# How to parse multiple integers

Tags: java, parsing, int

So I want to parse multiple integers by dividing them by `,` or space. Let's say user is only allowed to enter 4 numbers max. So how do I make multiple check if user enters for instance `( 1 2 4 3 )` or `(1 2 3)`? Because it would be not smart to make check for every different choice made. ( currently I'm only checking 4 choices 1, 2 3 or 4) since he should not be able to make a choice of more than 4

```
String choose = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ("Some text"));
int userchoice = Integer.parseInt(choose);
if(userchoice ==1){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow multiple integer inputs separated by spaces,
then you can split the input on spaces and parse them one by one, for example:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ("Some text"));
for (String s : input.split(" ")) {
    int userchoice = Integer.parseInt(s);
    if (userchoice == 1) {    
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

If there may be spaces between the integers,
then you could make the splitting more robust:

```
for (String s : input.trim().split("\\s+")) {
```

Comment: Nice, that worked. And how do I check if input is only single input or multiple ?

Comment: @LOXATRON77 `choose.split(" ").length`